# Свойство display: table-cell не срабатывает на инпутах

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, input, layout

Нужно сделать, чтобы кнопки в ряд занимали всю ширину `.row`.

Сейчас они смещены влево и не тянутся на всю ширину, хотя им присвоено свойство `display: table-cell;`.

Вопрос: почему `display: table-cell` не работает для инпутов? И можно ли достичь желаемого результата не оборачивая `input` в дополнительные `div`?

```css
.row{
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 1px 0;
  background-color: #eee;
 }
.input{
  display: table-cell;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 1">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 2">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 3">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 4">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно переделывать на Flexbox, если количество кнопок неизвестно:

```css
.row {
  height: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
.row input {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 1">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 2">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 3">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 4">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 5">
</div>
```

Или же поставить ширину 25%, если их количество фиксированно:

```css
.row{
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 1px 0;
  background-color: #eee;
 }
.input{
  width: 25%;
  /* Убираем влияние padding и border на конечную ширину input */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Обнуляем margin */
  margin: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 1">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 2">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 3">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 4">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, в моем случае, сейчас подойдет. Но я не хотела явно задавать ширину кнопок, так как их количество может измениться. Получается в данном раскладе такое невозможно?

Comment: @kizoso смотрите на первый вариант. Там не указана фиксированная ширина.

Comment: @kizoso только что добавил пятый элемент и он нормально встал.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы кнопки были в один ряд, а получается если на флексбоксах, то два

Comment: Вижу исправления. Спасибо, ваш ответ более полный, отмечу его. Хотя все равно не поняла почему табличное отображение на инпутах не сработало.

Comment: @kizoso Насколько я понял, не до конца было продумано как table-cell будет работать с элементами формы. Рекомендуют оборачивать инпут в див и уже к нему применять table-cell.

Answer (score 3):

Можно заменить `display: table` на `display: flex` + добавить свойство для потомков `flex-grow: 1`.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 1px 0;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 1">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 2">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 3">
  <input class="input" type="button" value="Кнопка 4">
</div>
```

Comment: Да, именно то что нужно, только не поняла, почему сначала сразу поставили минус. Это работает не во всех последних браузерах?

Comment: потому что юзер из соседнего ответа не любит мои ответы, видимо )
работает это везде, поддержка флексбокса достаточно хорошая, но не забывайте пользоваться автопрефиксером, если хотите поддерживать более ранние версии.

Comment: @kizoso обратите внимание, что ответ, который вы приняли, является велосипедом с точки зрения правильности использования флексбокса + свойство `page-break-inside: avoid` там не нужно.